# Error #CS0029 "cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string' in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

```
String URL = webBrowser1.Navigate ("http://45.84.196.206/youtube.php?ip=" 
    + IP.Text + "& port=" + Port.Text + "&time=" + Time.Text + "&method=" + Methods.Text);
```

This is what im trying to write but I keep getting the error #CS0029 "cannot implicitly convert type `void` to `string`", what can I do to fix this?

yes it returns void

Comment: What does the `Navigate(string)` method return? Is it perhaps `void`? If so: what string are you trying to capture? (Side note: you want to url-encode those textbox value, and remove the space in `& port=`)

Comment: [`Navigate(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigate?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_WebBrowser_Navigate_System_String_) does indeed return void, as those docs say it _Loads the document at the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL) into the WebBrowser control, replacing the previous document._

Comment: Method `Navigate` is used to load the document at the specified location into the WebBrowser. It doesn't return any value. What did you want to store in variable `URL`?

Answer (score 2):

I used an interpolated string indicate by $ preceding the string. With this you can insert variables directly into the string surrounded by braces. I also added the @ which marks the string as a verbatim string literal so any escape characters are ignored.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = $@"http://45.84.196.206/youtube.php?ip={IP.Text}&port={Port.Text}&time={Time.Text}&method={method.Text}";
        Debug.Print(s);
       webBrowser1.Navigate(s);
    }
```

I think the `Debug.Print` requires `using System.Diagnostics;` at the top of the file. You can look at the string your are sending and see if it is what you expected.

Comment: I know it is inherited from the OP's version, but this should really do some URL-escaping